# Firebase functions python init ends up in unexpected error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am trying to enable cloud functions in my application, but whenever i enter the firebase init functions and choose python as language and do either yes or no to all three prompts it ends up in unexpected error.

```
C:\Users\xxx\AndroidStudioProjects\xxxx> firebase init functions

You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:

  C:\Users\xxx\AndroidStudioProjects\xxxx

? Are you ready to proceed? Yes

=== Project Setup

First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add,
but for now we'll just set up a default project.

? Please select an option: Use an existing project
? Select a default Firebase project for this directory: xxxxx-xxx (xxxx)
i  Using project xxxxx-xxx (xxxx)

=== Functions Setup
Let's create a new codebase for your functions.
A directory corresponding to the codebase will be created in your project
with sample code pre-configured.

Functions can be deployed with firebase deploy.

? What language would you like to use to write Cloud Functions? Python
? File functions/requirements.txt already exists. Overwrite? No
i  Skipping write of functions/requirements.txt
? File functions/.gitignore already exists. Overwrite? No
i  Skipping write of functions/.gitignore
? File functions/main.py already exists. Overwrite? No
i  Skipping write of functions/main.py

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Comment: If you're having a problem with the Firebase CLI that's not related to any code you've written, you should consider filing an issue on its [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) along with your steps to reproduce the issue from a clean installation and working directory.